# how do you make sudo save the password?

Tags: linux, sudo

how do you set it so that sudo doesn't prompt you for your password every time? i have root.

Answer (score 7):

Use the NOPASSWD option in /etc/sudoers.

This is generally a bad idea, though, as any user who gets access to an account that run commands through sudo without a password may be able to compromise the system.

Also, sudo should remember your password for a period of time.  If this is timing out too soon for your tastes, you can increase the timeout by following instructions here: http://forums.macosxhints.com/showthread.php?t=83344

Comment: True, however be aware that sudo remembers it for each shell differently.
So If you are using multiple terminal windows you have to use it at least one in each.

Answer (score 1):

`man sudoers` is your friend. It explains all about `NOPASSWD` and the sudoers file, which you should edit with `visudo`.