# How to temporarily disable the JVM network connection

Tags: java, linux, networking

I need to test if a certain method can still function properly when the internet connection is down.

This test could be run on Linux, Windows or even on Jenkins in a VM, so OS-specific solutions aren't the best approach, I think. I also think that altering the security policy file is not ideal.

The ideal execution flow would look like this:

```
disableNetwork()
testMethod()
enableNetwork()
```

Comment: There is no 'JVM network connection' to disable. Pull the cable.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was clear enough in my question.

Comment: You will need to disable the network adapter at the OS level.

Comment: @JimGarrison I saw that on old answers here, but I was hoping that another solution would be available now. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been said in other answers around here, there is no Java native way of doing this. Therefore a OS solution is needed. This is what I have done for Linux:

```
public void pullTheCable() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo ifconfig eth0 down");
}
```

This will disable yout network adapter. (replace the 'eth0' with your corresponding adapter). And this will put it up again:

```
public void pushTheCable() {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo ifconfig eth0 up");
}
```

You will also need to edit the file /etc/sudoers to give the permission to the user to execute a sudo command whithout asking for a password. More on that here:

[how do you make sudo save the password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715908/how-do-you-make-sudo-save-the-password/715940)

As soon as I have a Windows solution i will update this answer.